# Questions regarding glibc startup code for X86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, glibc

I am looking into the startup code in Glibc for x86-64, and I am curious about the below two places which I highlighted in the screenshot directly.

Code: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/start.S

1. Why do we need to store the so-called "garbage" on stack?
2. Why do we just simply reset the registers r8 and rcx instead of passing the function pointers of .init and .fini to them?

[image]

Comment: I think for 1. the stack alignment is always 16 bytes

Comment: @Sebastian You mean for calling __libc_start_main?

Comment: For any call according to the System V ABI https://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI "The stack is 16-byte aligned just before the call instruction is called."

Answer (score 3):

`pushq %rax` is needed for stack alignment: RSP % 16 == 0 before any `call` instruction.

In current ELF version, ELF constructors and destructors are identifiable through [dynamic tags](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#init_fini) (`DT_INIT_ARRAY` and `DT_FINI_ARRAY` is generally preferred because of improved unwinding support). In glibc before version 2.34, the statically linked startup code (of which the quoted assembler fragment is a part) actually had its own loop to process `DT_INIT_ARRAY`. In glibc 2.34, this code was removed because it turned out that [it contained a very generic jump-oriented programming (JOP) gadget](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23323).

The `.init` function pointer is still passed as zero because this allows to share the implementation of `__libc_start_main` (which is called further down) for old and new binaries. glibc versions 2.34 and later look at this function pointer and call it if non-null, else use `DT_INIT` and `DT_INIT_ARRAY` to find the functions to call.

Another reason for making the `.init` change this way was that it was necessary to [change the startup code on *all* 21 glibc architectures](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=035c012e32c11e84d64905efaf55e74f704d3668), and it is easier to change a parameter to zero than to remove it because it does not affect the function signature or calling convention.

Pretty much the same rationale applies to the `.fini` change, except in this case, the old dynamically linked `__libc_start_main` implementation already ignored it.